# How to create thumbnails only for image files with Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I use the following code to create `Asset`s from the uploaded files:

```
def upload
  uploader = User.find_by_id(params[:uploader_id])
  params[:assets].each do |file|
    new_asset = uploader.assets.build(:asset => file) # Here the error appears
    new_asset.save
  end
  ...
end
```

I noticed that when I upload non-image files, e.g. `my.xlsx`, I got the following error:

```
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h "C:/temp/stream20110628-460-3vqjnd.xlsx[0]" 2>NUL
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: 
#<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: C:/temp/stream20110628-460-3vqjnd.xlsx is
not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

(For image files everything works fine: a thumbnail is created, and there is no error.)

Is that because Paperclip tries to create a thumbnail from `my.xlsx` ?

What configuration will **create thumbnails only for image files** ?

Here is some relevant code:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :uploader, :class_name => "User"
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :thumb => "80x80#" }
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used the following nice solution:

```
before_post_process :image?

def image?
  (asset_content_type =~ SUPPORTED_IMAGES_REGEX).present?
end
```

where:

```
SUPPORTED_IMAGE_FORMATS = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/bmp"]
SUPPORTED_IMAGES_REGEX = Regexp.new('\A(' + SUPPORTED_IMAGE_FORMATS.join('|') + ')\Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `has_attached_file` line to read:

```
has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { :thumb=> "80x80#" }, :whiny_thumbnails => false
```

This will prevent it from raising an error when thumbnails are not created. Note though that it won't raise errors if one occurs when processing an image though.

Comment: I don't like masking errors. It should be a nice way to define for which files a thumbnail will be created...